# Python3.6: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument for _io.BufferedReader.read(8)

Tags: python-3.x, io, bufferedreader

I have a Python line where I try to define a variable: `ts_parts = unpack('>8B', self.file.read(8))`, where self.file is an _io.BufferedReader object. Unfortunately, this returns the error: `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`, unless the # inside the read method is 0, in which case the complaint is of course: `struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 8`. Why is this happening? How can I fix it?